# Accepted way to access math functions in Clojure?

Tags: math, clojure

Recently I had to write some code involving math formulas in Clojure and I realized that there is the Java `java.lang.Math` library of functions and there is the `clojure.math.numeric-tower` library of functions.

Is this the accepted way to use math functions in Clojure, pulling from two different places to get the full complement? Or am I supposed to just use `Math`? Or something else?

Comment: I wonder why would you even raise this question: in what programming ecosystem using two non-conflicting libraries complementing each other would be disapproved?

Comment: Maybe there's not really a norm for use of these two libraries.  The fact that the numeric-tower library is still "in development" and contains very few functions--even though Clojure has been a fairly mature language in other respects for several years--suggests that the functions in this library aren't used that much by Clojure programmers.  My sense is that Clojure is still primarily used in business rather than by scientists. Or perhaps the existence of java.lang.Math has reduced the pressure on development of clojure.math.numeric-tower.

Comment: @leetwinski In what programming language are there competing definitions of basic mathematical functions? We're not talking about XML parsers. We're talking about the e^x function.

Comment: wouldn't call them competing. You just have to find out, why someone needed to make another e^x func. I bet there is a reason, considering some known java.lang.Math problems. For example i can see that e^x in numeric-tower promotes numbers to big integers if needed, which is nice, when you have really large power or base. Math is being basic, whereas others (since we are in a java world, let's enumerate some: Colt, Guava math, Apache commons math, JScience) just add missing functionality (or simplify existing) And it happens in all the languages i'm aware of.

Answer (score 1):

Using both or either as appropriate seems to be the norm.

Comment: And what about the duplicates, such as `Math/pow` and `math/expt` ?

Comment: From the code I've read 'appropriate' really is the keyword here. I can't speak for other programmers but I'm lazy. I'll start with java Math and only go hunting for a replacement when it proves not as suitable.